NodeJS WebRTC - RTCAudioSource - Expected a .byteLength of 480, not 2770
I'm trying to have my nodejs backend act as a peer that streams pcm audio to the browser via webrtc (https://github.com/WonderInventions/node-webrtc). (let's assume it's the only way to achieve what I need)
I'm creating an RTCAudioSource, and adding to it an array of chunked buffers - PCM 24k sample rate signed 16-bit little-endian.
RTCAudioSource/onData only accepts an Int16Array in samples, so I tried converting the buffers:
import { nonstandard } from '@roamhq/wrtc';

const source = new nonstandard.RTCAudioSource();

const samples = new Int16Array(
  buffer.buffer,
  buffer.byteOffset,
  buffer.byteLength / Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
);

// adding a single chunk. in practice I'm adding many more chunks
// throws "Expected a .byteLength of 480, not x"
source.onData({
  samples,
  sampleRate: 24000,
  bitsPerSample: 16,
  channelCount: 1,
});

source.onData() throws the following error, with x being anywhere from 17 to 2770 depending on the chunk size:
Expected a .byteLength of 480, not x

It's worth noting that the PCM buffers play fine when writing them to a wav file or when emitting and playing them in the browser via web sockets.

Some questions. (a) how big is the buffer when you start and (b) why not buffer.byteLength / 2, given that we all know 16 bits covers 2 bytes? If you could show a [mcve] that'd probably help a fair bit. Also, if the library docs suggest this should work, have you already asked why you're getting errors (and looking through both their open and closed their issues to see if others ran into this too?)
